# Modify file if file name contains with openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I want to modify all xlsx files that have the word "final" in the file name. I have a script that modifies all xlsx based on the extensions with this code below. What can I change to make it look for the "final" in the name?

```
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folder_list = os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for name in file:
        if name.endswith(".xlsx"):
```

I tried if name.contains("final") however I got the error the object has no attribute 'contains'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name.contains won't work for a python string. Instead try:

```
if 'final' in name:
    do_something(name)
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was putting the word "final" at the begging of all the files and used if name.startswith and that solved it. Your answer also works. Thank you